# Evaluating $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2\ln{(2k)} - \ln{(2k-1)} - \ln{(2k+1)} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was trying to evaluate the following series, which I know converges:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2\ln{(2k)} - \ln{(2k-1)} - \ln{(2k+1)} \tag{1}\label{1} $$

In a telescoping fashion, I began writing out the terms in hopes to find a pattern:

$$= (2\ln{2} - \ln{1} - \ln{3}) + (2\ln{4} - \ln{3} - \ln{5}) + (2\ln{6} - \ln{5} - \ln{7}) + \ldots \tag{2}\label{2}$$

while nothing canceled out, I grouped terms together:

$$ = 2\ln{2} - 2\ln{3} + 2\ln{4} - 2\ln{5} + 2\ln{6} - 2\ln{7} + \ldots \tag{3}\label{3}$$

$$ = 2 \left[ \ln{2} - \ln{3} + \ln{4} - \ln{5} + \ln{6} - \ln{7} + \ldots \right] \tag{4}\label{4}$$

which left me with the following divergent series:

$$ = 2 \sum _{k=2} ^{\infty} (-1)^k \ln{k} \tag{5}\label{5}$$

Clearly, $\eqref{5}$ can't be equivalent to $\eqref{1}$.

I'm pretty new to calculus, and while I've covered telescoping series, it seems that this technique cannot be applied here. Though, I don't know why.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: When an infinite series has both positive and negative terms, you can't re-arrange the terms; this could change the value of the sum completely. Check out the article on absolute convergence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence

Comment: The formulas of Stirling, Wallis,  Euler, and the Gamma function that are cited in the Answers and Comments are advanced. You can easily derive the Wallis Product for $\pi$ from  the value of your series, so don't expect an elementary answer.  When $\pi$  shows up in calculus it's often a sign of trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Let $S_N$ be the sum of the first $N$ terms.

Then
$$\exp(S_N)=\prod_{k=1}^N\frac{(2k)^2}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}
=\frac{4^N N!^2}{(2N+1)(1\times 3\times 5\cdots\times (2N-1))^2}
=\frac{16^N N!^4}{(2N+1)(2N)!^2}.$$
You can now attack this with Stirling's formula.

Comment: +1. Impressive yet so simple!

Comment: Even more straightforward would be to simply refer to the Wallis Product.

Comment: @NMK. I agree , considering that we can easily show that $n!\sim (n/e)^n\sqrt {kn}$ for some $k>0$ but to prove that $k=2\pi$ is  essentially to prove the Wallis Product  formula.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer of the series. With expansion of $\ln$ we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2\ln(2k)-\ln(2k-1)-\ln(2k+1) 
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} -\ln\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2k}\right)-\ln\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2k}\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n\geqslant1} \dfrac{1}{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{2k}\right)^{2n} \\
&= \sum_{n\geqslant1} \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{2k}\right)^{2n} \\
&= \sum_{n\geqslant1} \dfrac{\zeta(2n)}{n2^{2n}} \\
&= \color{blue}{\ln\dfrac{\pi}{2}}
\end{align}
the last step proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857613/whats-the-series-of-sum-n-geqslant1-dfrac-zeta2nn22n).

Comment: We can also put $x=1/2$ into  a (diificult) result of Euler that $\sin \pi x=$ 
 $\pi x\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac {x^2}{n^2}).$

Comment: Of course it is. But it gives the wallis product (I think), and i didn't want to use it!